# ¿Cuál es mi error? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? - XML

Tags: java, android, xml, whatsapp

Ayuda, al intentar recompilar un WAMod del que soy desarrollador me sale un error en APKTool que no me ha salido antes, me dice esto:
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
Traducción: error: Error al analizar XML: no está bien formado (token inválido)
He leído un poco pero no he logrado arreglar mi error, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp" android:key="cat_wa">
    <Preference android:title="@string/gbinsta_title_pref" android:key="gbinsta_project" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/settings_faq" android:key="settings_faq" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key"     />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="HPWhatsApp: Todo tipo de contacto">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Hecho por Hector Paez">
        <Preference android:title="Visita la página oficial de Facebook" android:summary="Me Gusta para estar al tanto de actualizaciones">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://m.facebook.com/todoparaandroid.hp/" />
        </Preference>
        <Preference android:title="Visita la página web oficial" android:summary="Descarga la versión oficial de HPWhatsApp siempre aquí">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://hpwhatsapp.epizy.com" />
        </Preference>
        <Preference android:title="WhatsApp de Héctor Paez" android:summary="¿Tienes alguna duda o agradecimiento?, hablalo con el desarrollador">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749&text=%C2%A1Hola!" />
        </Preference>
        <Preference android:title="Visita el grupo oficial de WhatsApp" android:summary="Ingresa al grupo oficial de HPWhatsApp, TODO PARA ANDROID">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://chat.whatsapp.com/KS47CLWhESLIZLYEBr5mpW" />
        </Preference>
        <Preference android:title="Dona a mi trabajo" android:summary="No obtengo beneficio al hacer HPWhatsApp, tu donación es apreciada">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWA modded by Hector Paez" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/pref_twitter" android:key="twitter" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_twitter" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/gb_auto_reply">
    <Preference android:title="@string/gb_auto_reply" android:key="gb_auto_reply_key" android:summary="@string/gb_auto_reply_sum" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
    <Preference android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
    <Preference android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
    <ListPreference android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Hola @HectorPaez. El idioma de este sitio es español, por favor, traduce tu pregunta para que se adecúe al sitio. Además te recomendaría leer [ask] para que puedas rehacer tu pregunta y que sea de buena calidad.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí, quería preguntarlo en el sitio en inglés ya que siento que tiene más comunidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que tenes que "urelencodear" los textos que tienen enlaces con parámetros, el error de parseo estaría en `&text=%C2%A1Hola!" />` y XML toma `text` como una referencia a otra entidad por el `&` y al no tener un `;` detrás salta el error.

en estos 2 hilos recomiendan reemplazar el `&` por un `&amp;`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112363/1423096

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6483807/1423096

Comment: Lo pude corregir anoche con un verificador pero mil gracias igualmente porque estabas en lo correcto. Gracias por tu tiempo^^.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que revisar el archivo si lo despliegas debe mostrarte un problema agregando un indicador rojo al lado derecho. En este caso muestra un caracter no codificado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso puedes usar el [codigo html](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

```
&#38;
```

o también

```
&amp;
```

por ejemplo en tu entrada tienes

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749&text=%C2%A1Hola!
```

cambiarías a (usando `&#38;`) :

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749&#38;text=%C2%A1Hola!
```

o también a (usando `&amp;` ):

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749&amp;text=%C2%A1Hola!
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.